# IIS Redirect to 404 all paths except one

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have multiple domains bound to one site. For one domain, I would like to leave everything untouched by the Rewrite module. For the other domain, for example: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), I wish to allow every request down this path [www.example.com/allowedpath](http://www.example.com/allowedpath) yet for any other requests from [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and below, return a 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, I understand that you want to achieve requirement below.

**Domain1.com -> Should not be affected by Rewrite rule**

**Example.com -> Example.com/allowed_path**

**Example.com/any_other_path -> Abort request**

To achieve the above requirement, I have created 2 rewrite rules below.

```
<rules>
         <clear />

                <rule name="Rule-1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="example.com" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="/test_path" />
                </rule>

                <rule name="Rule-2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="example.com" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/test_path" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="AbortRequest" />
                </rule>
</rules>
```

**Test result with Domain1.com**

[image]

**Test result with Example.com**

[image]

Further, you could modify these rules as per your own requirement.